# NodeJS crashes after sometime of leading a csv file

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, crash, large-data

I've been working on a project that outputs xml upon reading a csv, I use the `fs.createReadStream()` method to read the csv file but after some time, the terminal just crashes.

And I get

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\Programming\Node Projects\DAE Parser\main.js:13
      row["Value"].includes("tri") ||
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

It doesn't read the whole file.

here's what i'm doing

```js
fs.createReadStream("test.csv")
  .pipe(csv())
  .on("data", row => {
    if (
      row["Value"].includes("tri") ||
      row["Value"].includes("vt") ||
      row["Value"].includes("vx") ||
      row["Value"].includes("vn")
    ) {
      console.log(row)
    }
  })
```

Comment: What it `row["Value"]` doesn't exists?

Comment: As far as I understand, there's one for every column

Comment: IMO, there are two reasons for this. **1.** The value of `row["Value"]` doesn't exists. **2.** The value of `row["Value"]` neither string nor array. Its something else.

Answer (score 1):

Your `row["Value"]` is undefined, you can add a condition to check if it's falsy

```
fs.createReadStream("test.csv")
  .pipe(csv())
  .on("data", row => {
    if (row["Value"] && (
      row["Value"].includes("tri") ||
      row["Value"].includes("vt") ||
      row["Value"].includes("vx") ||
      row["Value"].includes("vn")
    )) {
      console.log(row)
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is vulnerable in cases where:

1. `row` is not an object
2. `row["Value"]` does not exist or is not an array.

If you want to be completely safe against these in any particular row, then you can do this:

```
fs.createReadStream("test.csv")
  .pipe(csv())
  .on("data", row => {
    if (typeof row === "object") {
      let arr = row.Value;
      if (arr && Array.isArray(arr) && (
        arr.includes("tri") ||
        arr.includes("vt") ||
        arr.includes("vx") ||
        arr.includes("vn")
      )) {
        console.log(row);
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: @himanshusardana - Did this answer your question? If so, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure. If this didn't answer your question, please comment about which part of your question you're still confused about.